# 240 width device sets broswer to 320

Tags: android, android-webview, media-queries

I am developing a mobile version of a website and I am using css query's to target ldpi,mdpi,hdpi devices. First I got in HTML:

```
meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, target-densitydpi=device-dpi, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

meta content="true" name="HandheldFriendly">

link href="css/stylemob.css" media="handheld, only screen and (max-width: 480px), only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)"  type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I have tested it on different devices.It works like a charm on hdpi and mdpi, but on the ldpi device(i.e with 240px width res) there are white areas on the left and right of the site(I have checked that browser opens the right css) with enabled scrolling like the browser opens css for 320px width min res.

**Question**:

1. Is the code wrong?
2. is there a way to fix it from html, css, javascript or directly from
   java-android code, since i will eventually integrate the web site
   opening from a WebView app.